# OpenCV network (IP) camera frames per second slow after initial burst

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu-12.04, ip-camera

EDIT: Upgrading to OpenCV 2.4.2 and FFMPEG 0.11.1 seems to have solved all the errors and connection problems, but it still hasn't solved the slow-down of frame rate.

I am using the default OpenCV package in Ubuntu 12.04 which I believe is 2.3.1. I am connecting to a Foscam FI8910W which streams MJPEG. I have seen where people have said that the best way is to use opencv+libjpeg+curl since [it is faster than the gstreamer solution](http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/Integration-of-Gstreamer-with-Opencv-code-td7196046.html). However, I can occasionally (50% of the time) connect to the camera from OpenCV as it is built and get a video stream. This stream starts out at around 30 fps for about 1 s but then slows down to 5-10 fps. The project I am working on will require having 6 of cameras preferably running at 15-30 fps (faster is better).

Here are my questions:

1. Is this a problem that is fixed in 2.4.2 and I should just
   upgrade?
2. If not, any ideas why I get a short burst and then it
   slows down?
3. Is the best solution still to use curl+libjpeg?
4. I see lots of people who say that solutions have been posted, but
   very few actual links to posts with solutions. Having all the actual
   solutions (both curl and gstreamer) referenced in one place would be
   very handy as per http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/IP-camera-solution-td7345005.html.

Here is my code:

```
  VideoCapture cap;
  cap.open("http://10.10.1.10/videostream.asf?user=test&pwd=1234&resolution=32");
  Mat frame;
  cap >> frame;
  wr.open("test.avi", CV_FOURCC('P','I','M','1'), 29.92, frame.size(), true);
  if(!wr.isOpened())
  {
    cout << "Video writer open failed" << endl;
    return(-1);
  }
  Mat dst = Mat::zeros(frame.rows + HEADER_HEIGHT, frame.cols, CV_8UC3);
  Mat roi(dst, Rect(0, HEADER_HEIGHT-1, frame.cols, frame.rows));
  Mat head(dst, Rect(0,0,frame.cols, HEADER_HEIGHT));
  Mat zhead = Mat::zeros(head.rows, head.cols, CV_8UC3);
  namedWindow("test", 1);
  time_t tnow;
  tm *tS;
  double t1 = (double)getTickCount();
  double t2;
  for(int i = 0; i>-1 ; i++) // infinite loop
  {
    cap >> frame;
    if(!frame.data)
      break;
    tnow = time(0);
    tS = localtime(&tnow);
    frame.copyTo(roi);
    std::ostringstream L1, L2;
    L1 << tS->tm_year+1900 << " " << coutPrep << tS->tm_mon+1 << " ";
    L1 << coutPrep << tS->tm_mday << " ";
    L1 << coutPrep << tS->tm_hour;
    L1 << ":" << coutPrep << tS->tm_min << ":" << coutPrep << tS->tm_sec;
    actValueStr = L1.str();
    zhead.copyTo(head);
    putText(dst, actValueStr, Point(0,HEADER_HEIGHT/2), fontFace, fontScale, Scalar(0,255,0), fontThickness, 8);
    L2 << "Frame: " << i;
    t2 = (double)getTickCount();
    L2 << "  " << (t2 - t1)/getTickFrequency()*1000. << " ms";
    t1 = (double)getTickCount();
    actValueStr = L2.str();
    putText(dst, actValueStr, Point(0,HEADER_HEIGHT), fontFace, fontScale, Scalar(0,255,0), fontThickness, 8);
    imshow("test", dst);
    wr << dst; // write frame to file
    cout << "Frame: " << i << endl;
    if(waitKey(30) >= 0)
      break;
  }
```

Here are the errors listed when it runs correctly:

```
Opening 10.10.1.10
Using network protocols without global network initialization. Please use avformat_network_init(), this will become mandatory later.
Using network protocols without global network initialization. Please use avformat_network_init(), this will become mandatory later.
[asf @ 0x701de0] max_analyze_duration reached
[asf @ 0x701de0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
[asf @ 0x701de0] ignoring invalid packet_obj_size (21084 656 21720 21740)
[asf @ 0x701de0] freeing incomplete packet size 21720, new 21696
[asf @ 0x701de0] ff asf bad header 0  at:1029744
[asf @ 0x701de0] ff asf skip 678 (unknown stream)
[asf @ 0x701de0] ff asf bad header 45  at:1030589
[asf @ 0x701de0] packet_obj_size invalid
[asf @ 0x701de0] ff asf bad header 29  at:1049378
[asf @ 0x701de0] packet_obj_size invalid
[asf @ 0x701de0] freeing incomplete packet size 21820, new 21684
[asf @ 0x701de0] freeing incomplete packet size 21684, new 21836
Using network protocols without global network initialization. Please use avformat_network_init(), this will become mandatory later.
Using network protocols without global network initialization. Please use avformat_network_init(), this will become mandatory later.
[asf @ 0x701de0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Successfully opened network camera
[swscaler @ 0x8cf400] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv422p to bgr24.
Output #0, avi, to 'test.avi':
Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg1video (hq), yuv420p, 640x480, q=2-31, 19660 kb/s, 90k tbn, 29.97 tbc
[swscaler @ 0x9d25c0] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv422p to bgr24.
Frame: 0
[swscaler @ 0xa89f20] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv422p to bgr24.
Frame: 1
[swscaler @ 0x7f7840] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv422p to bgr24.
Frame: 2
[swscaler @ 0xb9e6c0] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv422p to bgr24.
Frame: 3
```

Sometimes it hangs after the first `Estimating duration from bitrate` statement

Comment: Are you sure it's not a camera problem? Could you try pointing the camera at bright light and then check the framerate?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? want to pick an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the code that writes to disk?  I've seen very similar performance issues with USB cameras when a disk buffer fills up.  Great framerate at first, and then it drops dramatically.

If that is the issue, another option is to change your compression codec to something that compresses more significantly.

Answer (score 0):

A fast initial FPS that changes to a slow FPS would suggest that the camera is increasing exposure time to compensate for a poorly lit subject.  The camera is analyzing the first few frames and then adjusting the exposure time accordingly.

It seems that actual FPS is a combination of two things:

1. Hardware Limitations (defines the max FPS)
2. Required Exposure Time (defines the min FPS)

The hardware may have the bandwidth required to transfer X FPS, but poorly lit conditions may require an exposure time that slows down the actual FPS.  For example, if each frame needs to be exposed for 0.1 seconds, the fasted FPS will be 10.

To test for this, measure FPS with the camera pointed at poorly lit subject and compare that to the FPS with the camera pointed at a well lit subject.  Be sure to exaggerate the lighting conditions and give the camera a few seconds to detect the required exposure.